# Global Authority for Blacklisting IPs

Tags: .htaccess, blacklist, security, spam

I know that there are few common ways to block `attacking IPs` (such as `deny in htaccess`). Additional to that, we could get a huge list of IPs to block from misc sites such as :

1. http://www.okean.com/antispam/cnkr_htaccess.txt
2. http://www.stopforumspam.com

However, it looks very inefficient to block all these already known "bad" IPs for every project and all via htaccess or so.

.

So I want to know:

A) if there is any `Global authority` that should `monitor and block` such IPs from the Internet all together for the whole Internet...

B) If there could be any `simple+fast+autoUpdate` `"list"` method (such as used in AdBlockPlus) for the projects (websites) and they will simple load IPs to block on daily basis and block them (while remaining low cost in server delays).

Comment: Just to possibly help, you may consider editing your question to explicitly state you are asking about web/forum/comment spamming and not email spam.  I know it is implied by the links and content, but still.

Comment: ok I have removed the work Spam as it was confusing you. Its NOT about email spam, but site protection.

Comment: btw, I've never used them, but http://www.cloudflare.com/features-security is on their FREE plan.  May be worth the investigation.

Comment: thanks but this would be just highly "service" specific. it wont a be "general" solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't believe noone's said anything; I guess I should.

A) No.  There is no such central authority for the internet.  Conceivably, ICANN could instruct the big US backbone networks not to route a particular netblock.  But even if such authority could be used, and if it were it wouldn't constitute a global address block, it certainly wouldn't be used for anything as unimportant as site spammers.

It is generally regarded as a strength of the internet that it has no central authority.  I certainly regard it so.

B) Of course there could, and I believe TheCleaner has suggested one in a comment above; thus proving that such a thing not only can but does exist.  But I do hope your question isn't asking for recommendations for such a service, because that would violate the FAQ and render this question off-topic.

Hopefully, that clears a few things up.

Comment: hmm. there should be some independent wiki type monitor (so that its not politically motivated). if there can be a central registrar, then why not central monitor? The "bad" guys have grown their skill, the "good" guys must also grow their shield..

Comment: I like your "I can't believe noone's said anything" :D

Comment: no I am not asking, neither looking for a service.

Comment: "there should be some independent wiki type monitor (so that its not politically motivated)" - is that you raising your hand to volunteer? :)